# htaccess remove .php extension from the following

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I need the .php extension removed from the browser address

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. The rewriting module cannot magically change the links you send out to the browser.

Comment: Would it be possible to detect if .php is in the url and if it is, it gets redirected to the url without ".php" in it. Then if no ".php" found it runs the rewrite rule I have in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to answer your comment below the question:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(.*)$ $1$2 [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However I do not really see a point in this. Where should the ".php" extension in those urls come from? I mean users won't write down a url to query your system themselves. Instead they click on a link and that link must be something you sent out before. So obviously your approach should be to send out links that do not contain that file name extension in the first place!

Comment: Yes, your correct, getting mixed up in my logic trying to ask parts of the big whole to construct the correct answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules for hiding `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]